# Salto de línea al guardar archivos con fs.writeFileSync (JS)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, web

estoy tratando de utilizar un archivo log para guardar cierta información, pero de la forma que estoy intentando guarda todo de forma lineal, me gustaría dar saltos de línea para que se vea más ordenado el archivo, ya que no se puede agregar datos al archivo (Corrijanme si estoy mal) lo que hago es leer el archivo, guardar su contenido en una variable y sobrescribir el archivo para agregar el nuevo contenido, ¿Hay alguna otra forma de hacer esto y agregar saltos de línea?
Mi código es:

```
var name = 'Omar';
var email = 'omar@gmail.com';
save(name, email);

function save(name, email){
    var fs = require('fs');
    var add1 = 'Nombre: ' + name;
    var add2 = 'Correo: ' + email;
    var read = fs.readFileSync("write.log", "utf8");
    fs.writeFileSync("write.log", read + add1 + add2);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por supuesto que puedes agregar un salto de línea, además no es necesario que realices la lectura del contenido del archivo para almacenarlo en una variable y luego reescribir todo el archivo para añadirle solo una línea.

Imagina que estás implementando un `log`, como tal parece que haces. ¿Crees que es eficiente leer todo el contenido del mismo? Si el archivo es pequeño tal vez no tengas problema, pero ¿que sucede con un archivo de varios cientos de miles de lineas?

No es óptimo para nada leer tal cantidad de lineas para luego agregar sólo una y volver a escribir todo nuevamente en el mismo archivo.

**`fs.appendFile()` al rescate**

Para lograr lo que te propones vamos a usar [`fs.appendFile()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_path_data_options_callback), que como su nombre indica, añade datos a un archivo de forma asíncrona.

Lo mejor de este método es que si el archivo en cuestión no existe,  entonces Node lo crea automáticamente.

Para añadir el salto de línea solo debemos agregar la secuencia de escape para salto de línea: `\n`.

Podemos construir la linea que vamos a añadir a nuestro archivo usando un *Template Literal* o [*Plantilla de cadena de texto*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) y en dicha plantilla agregamos el salto de línea correspondiente:

```
const lineOfData = `${timestamp} Nombre: ${name} Correo: ${email} \n`; // <= Hemos añadido un salto de linea al final de la cadena
```

Una forma de hacerlo es la siguiente:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const name = 'Mauricio Contreras';
const email = 'some@email.com';
const timestamp = (new Date(Date.now())).toUTCString();

const saveLog = (name, email, timestamp) => {
  const lineOfData = `${timestamp} Nombre: ${name} Correo: ${email} \n`;
  fs.appendFile('./data.txt', lineOfData, {encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'a'}, (error) =>{
    if (error) throw error;
    console.log('Nueva linea añadida correctamente');
  });
}

saveLog(name, email, timestamp);
```

También existe la versión sincrónica de dicho método: [fs.appendFileSync()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfilesync_path_data_options), sin embargo la opción recomendada siempre será la versión asíncrona.

Espero que esto aclare tu duda.